# How to transform path/string by collapsing repeated elements?

Tags: google-bigquery

There is a filed in my table that represents pathways like below:

```
Item1->Item1->Item2-> Item3->Item3->Item3->Item1
```

In most cases this is quite looong sequence with many instances of same consecutive Items.

How I can shorted above path to something like below? in BigQuery!

```
Item1(x2)->Item2->Item3(x3)->Item1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Using [Scalar JS UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/user-defined-functions) (*Standard SQL*) <-- would be my choice

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collapse_repeated(pathway STRING) 
RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE js AS """
  var items = pathway.split('->');
  short = ''; elem = items[0]; count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] !== elem) {
      if (short.length > 0) {short += '->'}
      short += elem; if (count > 1) {short += '(x' + count.toString() + ')';}
      elem = items[i]; count = 1;
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }
  if (short.length > 0) {short += '->'}
  short += elem; if (count > 1) {short += '(x' + count.toString() + ')';}
return short;
""";

WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item3->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item2->Item3->Item3->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item4" AS pathway 
  UNION ALL SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item2->Item3->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item2->Item3->Item3->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item1->Item4" AS pathway
  UNION ALL SELECT "Item1->Item1->Item1" AS pathway
  UNION ALL SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item2" AS pathway
)
SELECT collapse_repeated(pathway) AS shorten_pathway, pathway 
FROM YourTable
```

**Note**: Same JS can be easily “translated” to JS UDF in Legacy SQL

> Using [Window Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) (*Legacy SQL*)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT_UNQUOTED(IF(repeats=1, item, CONCAT(item, "(x", STRING(repeats), ")")), "->"), pathway
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(pos) AS ord, MIN(item) AS item, COUNT(1) AS repeats, pathway
  FROM (
    SELECT item, pos, IFNULL(grp, 0)AS grp, pathway FROM (
      SELECT item, pos, SUM(change) OVER(PARTITION BY pathway ORDER BY pos ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS grp, pathway
      FROM (
        SELECT item, pos, IF(item=next_item, 0, 1) AS change, pathway FROM (
          SELECT item, pos, LEAD(item) OVER(PARTITION BY pathway ORDER BY pos) AS next_item, pathway
          FROM (
            SELECT item, POSITION(item) AS pos, pathway FROM (
              SELECT SPLIT(pathway, "->") AS item, pathway FROM 
                (SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item3->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item2->Item3->Item3->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item4" AS pathway),
                (SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item2->Item3->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item2->Item3->Item3->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item1->Item4" AS pathway),
                (SELECT "Item1->Item1->Item1" AS pathway),
                (SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item2" AS pathway)            
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
  GROUP BY grp, pathway
  ORDER BY ord
)
GROUP BY pathway
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to convince myself that this was possible just through array manipulation (using standard SQL), and I came up with a solution. An alternate way to solve the problem would be to use analytic functions, where you could detect changes in item along the path.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION PartsToString(
    parts_and_offsets ARRAY<STRUCT<part STRING, off INT64>>) AS ((
  SELECT
    STRING_AGG(
      CONCAT(part_and_offset.part,
             IF(parts_and_offsets[OFFSET(off + 1)].off - part_and_offset.off = 1,
             "",
             CONCAT("(x", CAST(parts_and_offsets[OFFSET(off + 1)].off - part_and_offset.off AS STRING), ")"))))
  FROM UNNEST(parts_and_offsets) AS part_and_offset WITH OFFSET off
  WHERE off + 1 < ARRAY_LENGTH(parts_and_offsets)
));

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION PathwayToParts(pathway STRING) AS ((
  SELECT
    ARRAY_CONCAT(
      ARRAY_AGG(
        STRUCT(part, off)),
        [STRUCT("" AS part, ARRAY_LENGTH(ANY_VALUE(parts)) AS off)]) AS parts_and_offsets
  FROM (SELECT SPLIT(pathway, "->") AS parts),
    UNNEST(parts) AS part WITH OFFSET off
  WHERE off = 0 OR part != parts[OFFSET(off - 1)]
));

WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item3->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item2->Item3->Item3->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item4" AS pathway 
  UNION ALL SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item2->Item3->Item1->Item1->Item1->Item2->Item3->Item3->Item2->Item2->Item2->Item1->Item4" AS pathway
  UNION ALL SELECT "Item1->Item1->Item1" AS pathway
  UNION ALL SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item2" AS pathway
  UNION ALL SELECT "Item1->Item1->Item2" AS pathway
  UNION ALL SELECT "Item1->Item2->Item3" AS pathway
)
SELECT PartsToString(PathwayToParts(pathway)) AS parts_string
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Yes, I know this is your favorite area :o), so I left it for you. I still prefer JS UDF version as most readable and clean, but anyway +1 to you for your version. Btw, this was question to me from my internal users, so hope they will also try this option